# Using awk in a bash-script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I've been struggling to run an awk result as the arguments of a new awk command within a bash-script; something like this

```sh
    echo $(
        ag '^@' ~/dotfiles/shared/journal | 
        sed  's/\(^.*\.txt:\)\(.*\)/\2 \| \1/g' | 
        fzf | 
        awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS="";} { print "\"/", substr($1, 3, length($1)-3), "/,/^~+$/","\" ", substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) }' 
    ) | xargs -0 -I "{}" awk {}
```

To help eradicate (what I think is) inconsequential code to this problem,

```sh
    echo $(
        ag '^@' ~/dotfiles/shared/journal | 
        sed  's/\(^.*\.txt:\)\(.*\)/\2 \| \1/g' | 
        fzf --height=40% --layout=reverse --info=inline --border --margin=1 | 
        awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS="";} { print "\"/", substr($1, 3, length($1)-3), "/,/^~+$/","\" ", substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) }' 
)
```

gives me

```sh
"/@ Search Pattern/,/^~+$/" /home/sam/dotfiles/shared/journal/20210125.txt
```

and if prepend awk to this result, I get the answer I need.
But I'm not able to make it work with xargs; it gives no output...
Also, if I remove the xargs pipe, and substitue `echo` with `awk`, I get

```
awk: cmd. line:1: "/@
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ unterminated string
```

If I change the relevant quotation marks like so

```sh
awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS="";} { print "\047/", substr($1, 3, length($1)-3), "/,/^~+$/","\047 ", substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) }'
```

I end up with this error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: '/@
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

Is it even possible to create an awk command using the result of another awk-command?

**EDIT: with more explanations**
Here's an over-all picture of what I'm trying to do...
I have a bunch of text files in my `~/dotfiles/shared/journal` folder that have the following format

```markdown
@ Project Title 

# Heading 1
some random text here, you know, typical markdown stuff

# Another Heading
Something **bold** here, etc., basically a typical markdown file

~~~
@ Another Project Title
# Second Project's Heading 
Some more markdown 

~~~
```

So the ag script goes through all the files, and lists out all the project titles (so conveniently prefixed with the `@`)

the sed line makes it all pretty to be piped into fzf,
An average entry would look like this

```
2:@ Project Title | /home/sam/dotfiles/shared/journal/20210125.txt:
```

the awk line basically would take the output and reformat it so that it could be made into an argument, (looking like this)

```
'/@ Project Title/,/^~+$/' /home/sam/dotfiles/shared/journal/20210125.txt
```

So now, if I just take this result and prefix it with awk on my commandline like so

```sh
awk '/@ Project Title/,/^~+$/' /home/sam/dotfiles/shared/journal/20210125.txt
```

I would get

```
@ Project Title
# Heading 1
some random text here, you know, typical markdown stuff

# Another Heading
Something **bold** here, etc., basically a typical markdown file
~~~
```

But if I replace `echo` with awk, I get the errors mentioned above.

**End of EDIT**

** Side Note **
I would eventually want to pipe the markdown into weasyprint, but one thing at a time...

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do add samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: That's a [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) anyway.

Comment: It's not clear how you are attempting to run this.  Probably you are confused about what quoting you need and where to put it.

Comment: ... `awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS="";} { print "awk \"/", substr($1, 3, length($1)-3), "/,/^~+$/","\" ", substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) }' | sh` might actually do what you are hoping to do.

Comment: The third argument to `substr` is superfluous if you just want to print through the end of the string. Without seeing your data, it's hard to tell if that's what you actually want.

Comment: `echo $(...anything...) | ...` is generally better replaced with `...anything... | ...`; that's doubly true when your `...anything...` emits NUL-delimited output, which can't be represented as a string in bash and so can't be passed to `echo` at all.

Comment: (The other bug you run into there is the one described in [I just assigned a variable in bash, but `echo $variable` prints something different!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566) -- just as with `$variable` vs `"$variable"`, `echo $(somecommand)` has subtle bugs fixed by `echo "$(somecommand)"`... and some other, even-more-subtle bugs better fixed by switching to use `printf` instead, as discussed in detail at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was just using `echo` to debug my code. I'll remember to use `printf` next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting is not really going to make it through `xargs` the way you would like. It's not impossible to pull off, but I would instead do something like

```sh
ag '^@' ~/dotfiles/shared/journal | 
sed  's/\(^.*\.ejrnl:\)\(.*\)/\2 \| \1/g' | 
fzf |
awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS="";} { print "/", substr($1, 3, length($1)-3), "/,/^~+$/","\" ", substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) }' 
| sh
```

However, this could still go wrong if you have several identical titles in your file.  A more robust as well as simpler approach would extract the start and end line numbers while you are extracting the titles, and then just simply pass those through when you want to extract the whole journal entry.  Something like (untested)

```
awk '/^@/ { if(prev) print pf ":" prev "," FNR-1 ":" ptitle;
    prev=FNR; pf=FILENAME; ptitle=$0; }
END { if (prev) print pf ":" prev "," FNR ":" ptitle }' ~/dotfiles/shared/journal/**/*.md |
fzf --height=40% --layout=reverse --info=inline --border --margin=1 | 
while IFS=: read -r file lines _; do
    sed -n "$lines"p "$file"
done
```

Comment: I learnt something new. Extracting the start and end line numbers with awk, and that too from multiple files! Awk is a lot more powerful than I realized! Many thanks @tripleee

Comment: **Final Used Code** 
``` bash
awk '/^@ / { if(prev) print pf ":" prev+1"," FNR-2 ":" ptitle;
    prev=FNR; pf=FILENAME; ptitle=$0; }
END { if (prev) print pf ":" prev "," FNR ":" ptitle }' ~/dotfiles/shared/journal/*.txt |
fzf --height=40% --layout=reverse --info=inline --border --margin=1 | 
while IFS=: read -r file lines _; do
    sed -n "$lines"p "$file"
done
```

Comment: As you can see, posting code in comments isn't particularly useful. You are welcome to post an answer of your own if you think it is useful. But the code you posted looks pretty identical to mine, except the filename wildcard is different.